# Macbook Shutdown Problem

Tags: macbook-pro, shutdown

My Macbook doesn't shut down ! It gets stuck on a blue screen with a loading image and doesn't shut down. I recently have updated my Macbook but I don't know if it is the problem or not.

Comment: What do you mean by updated ? Is there a pending software upgrade waiting for a restart to be installed ?

Comment: I updated my Mac and it restarted after that. I don't thing anything is pending.

Comment: Sorry, but there's not nearly enough information here to help you troubleshoot this problem.  Please edit the question to provide machine/OS specs, a detailed description of how you first encountered the problem, steps you perform that reliably repeat the problem, and any relevant error messages from the console (`/Applications/Utilities/Console.app`).

Comment: I'm having this same problem with my 27'' iMac, I bought it last year refurbished and it has worked great until now; it started having the problem yesterday. I think it's with Snow Leopard, I encountered the problem yesterday when shutting down obviously, it is repeated every time I've tried to turn off the iMac since yesterday, and I haven't checked the console yet.

Comment: @AliBZ: you marked the answer as accepted. Did it help you to find the problem? What was it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to boot into Safe Boot? You can find the instructions for that here: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1455

Also, I would note the time you are shutting the computer down and then check Console and see what is logged at the time, perhaps that would give us some hints as to what is preventing your computer from shutting down.